# Creating dynamic combo have error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-easyui

I am trying to made one dynamic combo by using this [EsayUI Apis](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboBox)

My Idea is My combo should work by passing div. So I am passing div and then attaching my input. Things are working fine when I am using only html. But when I am creating input tag in html and attaching then it only appearing textbox not combo.

My Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/easyui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/PCCombo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myID" style="width:26%; background-color: lightblue;">
    <!-- <input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="
                    url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',
                    method: 'get',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    textField: 'text',
                    panelWidth: 350,
                    multiple:true,
                    label: 'Language:',
                    labelPosition: 'top'
                    ">
//-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var val = document.getElementById("myID");
        var myCombo = new NewCombo ({
                    "val" : val,
                    "url": 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',
                    "divID": "chart_line",
                    }); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS

```
NewCombo = function(args){
    debugger;
    var divDetails = args.val;
    var input = '<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language"\
                    style="width:100%;" data-options="\
                    url: "JSON/combobox_data1.json",\
                    method: "get",\
                    valueField: "id",\
                    textField: "text",\
                    panelWidth: 350,\
                    multiple:true,\
                    label: "Language:",\
                    labelPosition: "top"\
                    >';
    divDetails.innerHTML = input
}
```

Here I am getting error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parseOptions (jquery.easyui.min.js:16209)
    at Function.$.fn.validatebox.parseOptions (jquery.easyui.min.js:22880)
    at Function.$.fn.textbox.parseOptions (jquery.easyui.min.js:23440)
    at Function.$.fn.combo.parseOptions (jquery.easyui.min.js:29853)
    at Function.$.fn.combobox.parseOptions (jquery.easyui.min.js:30297)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easyui.min.js:30220)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.combobox (jquery.easyui.min.js:30215)
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this or suggest me any alternate options.

Comment: can you put the the code in http://www.jsfiddle.net so the other can test your code, and also please provide the version of jquery and jquery-easyui that you're using..